# rspec to stub several File.exists? calls

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a function with several File.exists? calls:

```
def create(one_filename, other_filename)
    raise Error, "One error" if File.exists?(one_filename)
    raise Error, "Other error" unless File.exist?(other_filename)
    .....
end
```

But I don't know the way to stub the second error. The spec is something as:

```
it "should not create an existing file" do
    File.stub(:exists?).and_return(true)
    expect {
        subject.create('whatever')
    }.to raise_error("One error")
    end
it "should has to exists the other filename" do
    File.stub(:exists?).and_return(false)
    expect {
        subject.create('whatever.yaml')
    }.to raise_error("Other error")
end
```

For the second spec (`it "should has to exists the other filename"`) the File exists? stub raises the first check.

What is the best way to spec the two raises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return multiple values for multiple calls, simply do:

```
File.stub(:exists?).and_return(false, true)
```

Or, preferably, use the new syntax:

```
Allow(File).to receive(:exists?).and_return(false, true)
```

Another option would be to stub the method according to its input variables:

```
Allow(File).to receive(:exists?).with(one_filename).and_return(false)
Allow(File).to receive(:exists?).with(other_filename).and_return(true)
```

This has the added value of actually testing the *behavior* rather than the *implementation*.

Comment: It's still coupled to the implementation, the test would fail if you replace `File.exists?(one_filename)` with `Kernel.test('e', one_filename)`.

Comment: What do you propose @Stefan?

Comment: @JohnFadria mocks and stubs always couple your test to your implementation. This doesn't have to be a problem, you just have to be aware of it. Actually touching the filesystem is the only way to decouple your test from the implementation.

Comment: @JohnFadria or use a gem which fakes the filesystem: https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs

Answer (score 0):

Actually

> Mocking calls to FileUtils or File means tightly coupling tests with the implementation.
>
> [fakefs](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs)

Just calling the following code before your stub should be enough.

```rb
allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_call_original
```

[source](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec/issues/746#issuecomment-247992778)